# Carbonation level over time

Tags: carbonation

Is there any research showing how carbonation develops over time on average?  I'm imagining a graph with the number of days since packaging on the x-axis and the current level of dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> on the y-axis.  I'm particularly interested in standard bottle conditioning as well as the "set and forget" method of force-carbonating kegs.

I'm sure this varies somewhat by the yeast strain, yeast health, temperature, ABV, and other factors, but I would imagine some kind of data like this probably exists for a fairly common set of assumptions (e.g. US-05, 68°F, 5% ABV, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottle conditioning is simply just more fermentation. To quantify how much CO2 is produced at a given time is subject to all the variables of fermentation. Yeast health, cell count, temperature, available fermentable sugars etc. So to graph this in a useable way would be next to impossible.

Force-carb plug and forget. This too is subject to all the different ways it can be done. Diffuser stone, top down, bottom up. Keg dimensions and volume play a big role too. I've not seen any carb charts published in a consolidated way to cover all methods.

If I'm not in a rush for the beer, I feel a top down plug and forget for a week+ gives the best results. Also helps as a final fining for a brilliantly clear beer. Top down carb seems to aid the settling of clouding particles. That being said, a bottom up carb will help keep those hazy particles up for that NE IPA.